# JMeter java.netSocketException / org.apache.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: spring, jmeter

I am doing load testing with JMeter on 4 microservices with a load balancer. When the number of threads is low no errors appear, however, when the number of threads exceeds 2000 without counting any ramp-up time two errors "java.net.SocketException" and "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException" appear.

I don't know if these errors appear because of the amount of concurrent accesses to the servers or because of the JMeter itself when creating the threads.

The balancer is configured to support this amount of accesses.

The microservices are developed using Spring, I have tried to modify the application.properties file with properties to increase the number of concurrent accesses and there has been no change.

From my point of view, I think that the microservices are working correctly, there are times when 2000 threads are running and these errors do not appear.

Would anyone know what is happening?

Thanks!
[Response codes per second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkWij.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the exceptions messages for both cases.

For example [HttpHostConnectException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/HttpHostConnectException.html) is a subclass of [ConnectException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html?is-external=true) and according to its JavaDoc:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port).

so I would say it's either microservice instance or loadbalancer issue.

With regards to [SocketException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html?is-external=true) you need to provide more details:

> Thrown to indicate that there is an error creating or accessing a Socket.

You can [increase JMeter's logging verbosity for HTTP procotol](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

additionally you can [enable Java network layer debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

These 2 hints will allow you to inspect what's happening on JMeter side.

In addition you can check your load balancer logs and access/server logs of the microservices. If there is nothing there you can also check operating system log files as you might hit some form of handles limit or something like this.